# How to use LibvlcSharp on Linux?

Tags: linux, libvlc, libvlcsharp

I'm trying to use LibvlcSharp on a linux installation (Ubuntu 18.04). I'm following all the instructions, including this one [Getting started on LibVLCSharp.Gtk for Linux](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/LibVLCSharp/blob/master/docs/linux-setup.md) but my application always crash. It's working perfectly on windows, because there we can add VideoLAN.LibVLC.Windows package, but I couldn't find someting similar for Linux.

My code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Record in a file "record.ts" located in the bin folder next to the app
        var currentDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
        var destination = Path.Combine(currentDirectory, "record.ts");

        // Load native libvlc library
        Core.Initialize();

        using (var libvlc = new LibVLC())
        //var libvlc = "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/";
        using (var mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(libvlc))
        {
            // Redirect log output to the console
            libvlc.Log += (sender, e) => Console.WriteLine($"[{e.Level}] {e.Module}:{e.Message}");

            // Create new media with HLS link
            var urlRadio = "http://transamerica.crossradio.com.br:9126/live.mp3";
            var media = new Media(libvlc, urlRadio, FromType.FromLocation);

            // Define stream output options. 
            // In this case stream to a file with the given path and play locally the stream while streaming it.
            media.AddOption(":sout=#file{dst=" + destination + "}");
            media.AddOption(":sout-keep");

            // Start recording
            mediaPlayer.Play(media);

            Console.WriteLine($"Recording in {destination}");
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

The error message:

> Unhandled Exception: LibVLCSharp.Shared.VLCException: Failed to perform instanciation on the native side. Make sure you installed the correct VideoLAN.LibVLC.[YourPlatform] package in your platform specific project
>      at LibVLCSharp.Shared.Internal..ctor(Func`1 create, Action`1 release)
>      at RadioRecorderLibVlcSharp.Program.Main(String[] args) in /media/RadioRecorderLibVlcSharp/Program.cs:line 19

Anyone can help me?

thanks

Comment: Did you install the libvlc and libvlc dev packages? which .net version are you using? .net core? mono?

Comment: Hi! Yes, I've installed libvlc and libvlc-dev packages. I'm using .net core 2.1 and I followed all the instructions installing mono etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try `apt-get install vlc`? That seems to help getting all the required plugins/deps on your system (though it will pull vlc 2.x from the official ubuntu rep probably).

Comment: Hi! It's working now after apt-get install vlc command. I already had vlc installed in my linux so I thought it was not necessary. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If this solves your issue, please mark it as an answer

Comment: Thanks, this is confusing since there is no nuget package for native linux libraries.

Unfortunately this also means it is not possible to do a fully bundled build of an app since this package is not available...

Comment: sadly we don't have the manpower to handle shipping and maintaining all the native linux builds on nuget